# How to bind CustomButton's text-property to CustomButton's Label?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, custom-controls

I am creating a custom button for my project. I created a dependency property for the button's text and put a label on the rectangle. now i would like to bind this text property to the label's content property.

the code of my label is

```
<Label x:Name="lblContent" Content="" Margin="8,16,24,18.04" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Background="#006C6C6C" Foreground="#FF00D6FF" FontSize="20" Padding="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
```

and this is my property

```
public CustomButton()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(CustomButton));
    }

    static DependencyProperty TextProperty;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)base.GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
```

but how can i add this databinding to it? i am not really experienced in databinding and google does not help me very much :(
in addition to my question: Are there any tutorials which explain this whole binding topic understandable for beginners? msdn or other sites i found do not explain it very well imho.

Comment: If you just want a label within the button to have the same text as the button, then you can switch the set method of Text to first set the text of the label.

Answer (score 1):

It would really help if you could show the complete XAML for the custom button, but assuming the Label is being created inside a ControlTemplate you could do the following (or something similar):

```
<Label x:Name="lblContent" Content="{TemplateBinding Text}" />"
```

If it doesn't work, please edit your question and add the XAML for the button..

Comment: This is correct... you should be binding the `Label.Content` to the Text `DependencyProperty`, and not the other way around.